# How does my output show real column headers INSTEAD OF AUTO INCREMENT NUMBERS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mysql-python

How does my output show real column headers instead of auto increment numbers.
[image]

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="***************",
    user="****",
    password="****")

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    query = "select * from odk_prod.individual_report_core where PROCESSED_BY_MIRTH = 0 "
    mycursor.execute(query)
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

    df = pd.DataFrame(myresult)

    print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the column names explicitly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall(), columns=[d[0] for d in cursor.description])
```

Comment: Hey thank you is just that i am working on a big database, but i will remember the pointer thank you

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of all columns which you want `df` to have. Example:

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Then do:

```
df.columns = cols
```

Comment: Hey thank you is just that i am working on a big database, but i will remember the pointer thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the cursor so it can return the dictionary object instead:

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor(dictionary=True)
```